# GluonMobile application doesn't start with JavaFX19

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Using the following dependencies

```
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
        <javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
        <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

        <java-version>17</java-version>
        <javafx-version>19</javafx-version>
        <charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
        <attach-version>4.0.15</attach-version>
```

with the template POM and graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final, an pplication can't start if it's using new JavaFX19 API methods. for example:

```
public class ConsoleView extends View {

    ListView<String> console = new ListView<>();

    public ConsoleView() {
        console.setCellFactory(listView -> {
            var cell = new ListCell<String>() {

                {
                    textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
                    textFillProperty().bind(textProperty().map(text -> {
                        if (text.contains("RED")) {
                            return Color.RED;
                        } else if (text.contains("ORANGE")) {
                            return Color.ORANGE;
                        }
                        return Color.BLACK;
                    }));
                }
            };
            return cell;
        });
        setCenter(console);
        console.getItems().add("RED");
        console.getItems().add("BLUE");
        console.getItems().add("GREEN");
        console.getItems().add("ORANGE");
    }
}
```

compiles and builds fine (and also runs on desktop fine from the IDE), but when launching on Android the following exception occurs:

```
D/GraalCompiled( 4642): Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.map(java.util.function.Function)
D/GraalCompiled( 4642):         at com.my.view.ConsoleView$1.<init>(ConsoleView.java:29)
D/GraalCompiled( 4642):         at com.my.view.ConsoleView.lambda$0(ConsoleView.java:25)
...
```

The method `javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.map` is [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and is since 19. Since there is no complication and build issue, the method has to have been found. Maybe there is some issue with dynamic linking.

The [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com) notes that the the JavaFX version has been bumped to 19-ea+8. Do I need to update something or wait for an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaFX version that you use in your pom:

```
<javafx-version>19</javafx-version>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

is used by the JavaFX Maven plugin (`mvn javafx:run`), or by the GluonFX Maven plugin (`mvn gluonfx:run`) to run on your VM and that works fine.

However, when you build a native image with `mvn gluonfx:build`, the plugin uses the static version of the JavaFX SDK, and that is by default set by the plugin.

The GluonFX Maven [plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin) based on your version:

```
<gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>
```

which is not the latest by the way (it is 1.0.15), [uses](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/Constants.java#L111) the JavaFX static SDK 19-ea+8.

However, the [issue](Map, FlatMap and OrElse fluent bindings for ObservableValue) that added this new API was merged only before 19-ea+10 was released.

Until a new version of the GluonFX plugin is released with JavaFX 19 GA or the new 20-ea versions, you can simply set your plugin to use them with [`javafxStaticSdkVersion`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_javafxstaticsdkversion):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
            <javafxStaticSdkVersion>19</javafxStaticSdkVersion>
            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin
```